# Vendor lib issue in app/code/Yireo/Webp2 module

Tags: magento2

I am using Yireo_Webp2 module. The issue is I have downloaded it from git and then activated it. it also have some dependencies so I have run composer update in app/code/Yireo/Webp2 folder which created a vendor folder in app/code/Yireo/Webp2.

Now these library are using autoload.php and it is included as `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` which referring magento's autoload. so my module's libraries are not getting called. It always displaying this class is not found etc. so how can I autoload these lib files? or should I shift them to magento's vendor folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Composer Install (Recommended)**

You don't need to do this much of steps, Only you have to do this following steps are:

Install Extension with command line:

```
composer require yireo/magento2-webp2
```

Automatically all required modules or files or lib are download with composer.

Then only you have to run Basic Magento Commands:

```
bin/magento module:enable Yireo_Webp2
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**And if you are Installing Manually**

You need to download the Folder Zip then Create the Path in your root project as:

Path: `app/code/Yireo/Webp2`

**Then Paste you zip and Extract then paste your whole code from webp2 to Folder Webp2.**

Now Run Basic Commands Such as:

```
bin/magento module:enable Yireo_Webp2
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Remove your existing code and Please Follow this steps either Composer way or Manually Installation.**

Comment: I have done manual installation but its not working as in manual installation lib files are not included. I guess composer way will be better.

Comment: Yes, Always Prefer composer.

Comment: I have installed it manually and at frontend it shows:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Laminas\Uri\Uri' not found in app/code/Yireo/Webp2/Image/File.php on line 54. so what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

One more workaround I have found for current scenario is that I have deleted that vendor folder of app/code/Yireo/Webp2. Then copied the libs in require section of magento's composer.json and run composer update.

Comment: okay, is there any issue you found on this?

Comment: no it also worked. it is for that modules which has their composer.json and we have manually installed them.

Comment: Okay. That's Great